# How to omit user interaction in gcloud

Tags: console, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I want to automatically delete instances in google compute engine.

For that I use gcloud `gcloud compute instances delete instance-name --zone instance-zone`

However gcloud asks me to confirm the action. Is it possible to omit this step and do it automatically?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
gcloud -q compute instances delete instance-name --zone instance-zone
```

(--quiet, -q Disable all interactive prompts.)

Comment: Note that --quiet, -q will choose the default action/answer for all the interactive prompts that are suppressed.

Comment: Isn't the default action for deleting instance "No"? If so then I don't think this answers the question, and in fact isn't actually possible?

Comment: I just checked, when --quiet is not passed the default is "N" for no. However, if you pass --quiet then the default changes to "Yes", which is completely unintuitive and ridiculous, but hey at least it's possible to automate cleanup.